# Why does the compiler return a useless value after I dereference it and perform some operation on it?

Tags: c, pointers

`j` is a pointer which points to `i`. The first print statement returns the value of `i`, but when I try to deference the pointer and increment `i` by 1, it returns a useless value which I suppose is the address of `i`. Why does this happen, and where can I read about pointers in more detail?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main( )
    {
        int i = 3, *j;
        j = &i ;
        printf ( "\nValue of i = %u", *j ) ;
        *j++;
        printf ( "\nValue of i = %u", *j ) ;
    }
```

After `*j++` I expect `j` to point to `i` and the value of `i` should now be 4. So when I print `*j` it should return 4.

Comment: Where do you expect `j` to point to after incrementing it? What value do you expect to see for the dereferenced value?

Comment: `*j++` returns the value pointed to by `j` which is actually 3 but you discard, and then increments `j` (the pointer, NOT the data pointed to). This is because the grammar for C parses it as equivalent to `*(j++)`. As a result, in the next line `*j` technically invokes Undefined Behavior and in practice reads a different and wrong memory location containing data that you have no knowledge of; this _might_ be the address of `i` or it might not. To increment the data `j` points to, use `(*j)++` or `++*j` or `++(*j)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think it should print 4

By that I assume you think you are incrementing `i`. But in fact you are incrementing the `j` pointer not the content that it is pointing to. This is because the C operator precedence says that `++` has higher precedence than `*`.

That is, `*j++` is doing:

1. `j++`
2. `*j`

The second step is a no-op as the result is not used.

What you actually want is: `(*j)++`

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find C syntax in detail?

Comment: You can read the [C standard](https://iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard). Though that may require payment. Or you can just consult any C book or tutorial as that may be an easier way to learn C syntax anyway.